# What is the southernmost landmass not covered by the Antarctic Treaty?

Tags: geography

I know [Bouvet Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouvet_Island) is quite south. Is there anything southern than that?

Comment: Because Earth Science is mostly about [physical processes](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and treaties aren't physical processes, I wonder if [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be better equipped to answer this question?

Comment: Good point, next time I'll have a question like this, I'll try there! :)

Comment: One could argue that knowing what is covered by the Antarctic Treaty is good information for Earth scientists, but yes that is not science per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Antarctic Treaty covers all areas greater than 60° south latitude. A look at a standard globe reveals that the **South Sandwich Islands** form a chain that nearly reaches but does not cross this parallel. These islands are under the sovereignty of the United Kingdom.

[image]

From https://ian.macky.net/pat/map/gs/gs.html